# Newbie: VirtualBox "no bootable medium found"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

My first foray into VM land so please excuse the stupidity expressed below.

Running VirtualBox on Kubuntu 9.10 and trying to set up a VM running Windows 7.  Windows 7 came installed and is functional as a dual-boot but I want to stay in kubuntu hence the VM.

Received "Fatal: no bootable medium found" when trying to start a VM.  Not surprising since VBox never gave me an option (that I recognized anyway) to tell it to look on the hard drive.

I did not receive a CD of Windows 7 with the machine.  How can I tell VirtualBox to grab what it needs from the hard drive?  Or am I out of luck because I don't have a CD?

---

Update: This might not be possible.  The installed Windows 7 is useful only to pull the installation key.  It is easier to just to download or get an ISO from a friend and enter in your own key.

Comment: Have you created a virtual hard drive? (VHD)?  Try reading http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#gui-createvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox doesn't support (that I *know* of, since I also tried it...) accessing a physical disk or partition as a virtual hard disk.

VMWare workstation will allow you to access a hard drive, but I'm not sure about separate partitions.

You're best option in this instance is to run Kubuntu in VirtualBox under Windows 7. That or see if you can get the install DVD from you're pc manufacturer.

Comment: Also, when I bought a e-machines laptop a few months ago, (with Vista) it included an option to create install DVD's for back up.  You could try that.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are 2 windows partitions - "system" and "factory_image".  I assume the latter is what I want but I don't know if it is an ISO.  Is there a way to either copy it to a dvd or use a program that will create an ISO from it?  Again, this is Win7.

Comment: Unfortunately, some PCs include a "restore image", which is not an actual install DVD, but rather an image of your system as it was brand new. "Restoring" your computer simply re-images the drive from the image partition. If your pc gives you the option to create "restore DVDs", do so, so that at the very least, you'll be able to restore the pc if the image partition gets wiped/corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#gui-createvm).  When setting up VirtualBox for the first time you need an operation system either from an .iso file or a CD, inserted in the drive.